# Class Variables Overriding

Tags: ruby, oop, class-variables

I was playing around with class variables, and I knew that I could override a class variable in a subclass but I didn't realize where I call a class method matters. For example;

```
class Vehicle
  @@wheels = 4

  def self.wheels
    @@wheels
  end
end

puts Vehicle.wheels #4
puts Vehicle.wheels #4
puts Vehicle.wheels #4

class Motorcycle < Vehicle
  @@wheels = 2
end
```

The `puts` statement outputs 4, that all makes sense to me because I figured that you `@@wheels` is not overridden until an object is instantiated from the `Motorcycle` class. So then I did this:

```
class Vehicle
  @@wheels = 4

  def self.wheels
    @@wheels
  end
end

class Motorcycle < Vehicle
  @@wheels = 2
end

puts Vehicle.wheels #2
puts Vehicle.wheels #2
puts Vehicle.wheels #2
```

Now once I move those three lines to after the class `Motorcycle` they output 2... even though a `Motorcycle` object hasn't been instantiated. This confuses me. In detail what is happening here? Is it because class variables are loaded when we try to access it? How is this possible?

Comment: _"until an object is instantiated from the Motorcycle class"_ – can you clarify this? You never create an instance of `Motorcycle` in the above code snippets.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, **instantiation has nothing to do with it**; this is a class variable, not an instance variable. Your code *never* instantiates anything; nor, as written, does it need to. We're just talking about some classes. But classes are first-class objects in Ruby, so that's fine.

Second, **order does matter**, because in Ruby *all statements are executable*. When you say

```
class Motorcycle < Vehicle
  @@wheels = 2
end
```

...all of that code executes *right now*, at the moment you say it — the moment when it is encountered as Ruby walks down the page obeying instructions. That code is not a mere template to be obeyed at some future time; it says: "create a Motorcycle class and set its class variable `wheels` to `2`, *now*."

Third, **you're not "overriding" anything**. In the class Motorcycle, `@@wheels` *is* the very same class variable `@@wheels` that you defined for Vehicle earlier. It is not some other variable that "overrides" it. This is a single value that works like a kind of namespaced global, reachable from the class, any subclasses, and any instances thereof.

For more information, see (e.g.):

- [How do I override a variable in a Ruby subclass without affecting the superclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382626/how-do-i-override-a-variable-in-a-ruby-subclass-without-affecting-the-superclass)
- [Ruby class instance variable vs. class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773552/ruby-class-instance-variable-vs-class-variable/15773671)
- https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/faq/8/

If you want something you *can* override, what you're looking for is probably more like an instance variable in a class context, often called a "class instance variable" — e.g. like this:

```
class Vehicle
  @wheels = 4
  class << self
    attr_reader :wheels
  end
end

class Motorcycle < Vehicle
  @wheels = 2
end

puts Vehicle.wheels # 4
puts Motorcycle.wheels # 2
```

Comment: So how does it do all that?

Comment: How does what do all what?

Answer (score 0):

All occurances of `@@wheels` refer to the exactly same variable. First you set it to 4, then you set it to 2. Why does it surprise you, that it has the value 2? Use `@wheels` instead (as matt) suggested, if you want to have a separate variable for both.

Having said this (and this is the only reason I'm writing this answer, because matt has already covered everything else in his answer), your usage of this "variable" suggests that is is supposed to be an invariable property of the respective class. That is, every motorcycle is supposed to have 2 wheels. In this case, it would perhaps make more sense to make it a constant of its class:

```
class Motorcycle < Vehicle
  WHEELS = 2
end

class Unicycle < Vehicle
  WHEELS = 1
end
```

and use it as

```
puts Motorcycle::WHEELS
```

If you have a variable v, where you only know that it is some subclasss of Vehicle,  you can write

```
puts v.class::WHEELS
```

Whether you also define WHEELS in the class Vehicle itself, its a design question. If you intend to treat `Vehicle` as abstract class, it does not make sense to define a fixed number of wheels in it. For orthogonality, you could catch this case by doing a

```
class Vehicle
  WHEELS = nil
end
```

if you want to, or just don't define it and rely on the fact that your code will raise an exception, if you try to access the wheels of something which is "just a plain vehicle".

If you do want to instantiate a `Vehicle`, of course it may make sense to set the constants there to, i.e., 4.

However, in this case I would consider allowing individual instances having a different number of wheels. The Reliant Robin was a car with 3 wheels, and trucks have sometimes 6 or 8 wheels. For maximum generality, I would therefore make the number of wheels an instance variable, and of course you can provide a default value:

```
class Vehicle
  attr_reader :wheels
  def initialize(wheels=4)
    @wheels=wheels
  end
end
class Motorcycle < Vehicle
  attr_reader :wheels
  def initialize(wheels=2)
    super(wheels)
  end
end

m = Motorcycle.new
puts m.wheels
```